# Accessing test file name from conftest.py

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm writing a small framework in python using pytest, and as part of the teardown I am taking a screenshot.
Now, I want that screenshot to be named according to the running test, not conftest.py
So, for example, my code right now is:

```
driver.save_screenshot(os.path.basename(__file__)+'.png')
```

**The problem**

This prints the name "conftest.py".
I want to print the calling test name if possible. I am guessing using requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the current file path via `request.node.fspath`. Example:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def currpath(request):
    return str(request.node.fspath)
```